# Export value of corresponding site out to a new text file

Tags: linux, bash, unix, scripting

I have a text file that contains two columns of data, the first column being a site ID and the second being a value. If the value is equal to 0, I want to send the corresponding site ID out to a new file. If the value is equal to 15, I want to do nothing.

**Text File:**

```
K5B2 0
K6B0 0
K6L4 0
K7W4 0
K8B0 0
K8G2 0
K8W2 0
KABE 15
KACK 15
KACY 15
KADW 15
KAFJ 15
KAFN 15
KAGC 15
KAKQ 15
KALB 15
KANP 0
KAOO 15
KAPG 15
KAQW 15
KART 15
KASH 15
KAUG 15
```

**Attempted Script:**

```
badcheck1=`00z_reingest_out_tmp | awk '{print $2}'`
badsitescheck=`00z_reingest_out_tmp | awk '{print $1}'`

if [ ${badcheck1} -eq "0" ];
then
echo "${sites} is fine"
else
echo "${badsitescheck}" >> out
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this simple awk script:

```
awk '$2 == 0 { print $1 > "file.out" }' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
cat test.txt | awk '$2==0{print$1}' > export.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for something to add additional scripting to you can use the following.  I often want to perform more than one action when I'm performing a check.

```
for i in $( cat 00z_reingest_out_tmp ); do
    if [[ ${i/#* } = 0 ]]; then
        echo "${sites} is fine"
    else
        echo "${i/% *}" >> out
done
```

- $( ) executes command and uses output as input to for command
- ${i/#* } start at beginning and remove pattern ( removes first word "*" and following space " " )
- ${i/% *} start at end and remove pattern ( space " " and following word "*" )

I hope this helps.

Note: I'm not sure where you got ${sites}, but I left it in there in case you defined it earlier in the code.

Note: I like @anubhava's answer above for a single line implementation, but it doesn't seem to fit exactly what you were trying to do in your script example.